# AngularJS application not downloading file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, csv

I have a rails server that generates a csv from an http request, like this:

```
@results = some_json_string
require 'csv'
csv_string = CSV.open("results.csv","wb") do | csv|
        JSON.parse(@results).each do |hash|
                csv << hash.values
        end
end
send_file('results.csv')
```

And an AngularJS application that requests this CSV file from the server

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
     $scope.csvSubmit = function() {
      var csv = $.post('http://ip_addr:3000/api/csv', { 'input': 'my_request' });
      csv.done(function(result){
         File.save(result, function(content){
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(content);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'result.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
      });
    });
   }
  }
])
```

It seems that, as the Angular app makes the http request, the Rails server sends over the csv file.

From the rails logs:

```
 GET /professional/maintain/status/ 200 224 - - 0 2908 - -\n"}
 Sent file results.csv (0.1ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 976ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

However, the Angular app does not successfully download the file to the client machine. Instead, the javascript console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function query.js:8
```

line 8 is this line:

```
File.save(result, function(content){
```

Anyone have an idea how to get this download working correctly?

**EDIT:** It could be a syntax thing, since I haven't actually written that much javascript. Bust as I'm looking at it I can't figure out why it would tell me undefined is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File has no method save [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), you should be able to accomplish the download via

```
 var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI('test,1234,1232,test');
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'result.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();
```

Without any of the File.save(result, function(content){}); functionality

Running the above code in console starts a download with the content I passed in.